# Возникла проблема с запуском json-server

Tags: javascript, npm

Пытался запустить json-server, но выдавало ошибку. Пытался запустить через консоль в Windows и в терминале VScode, но безуспешно. npm пакет установлен локально для проекта и папка db.json присутствует в проекте.
[image: Ошибка при запуске json-server]

Comment: Укажите полный путь к исполняющемуся файлу, а`ля: node_modules/.../json-server/...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить через команду **npx** json-server --watch db.json